# Does cocos2d support scaled position of ccsprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is a diagram of question.

Below diagram is sprites of cocos2d.

I want to get a position of yellow sprite when green sprite scaled from 1.0 to 0.5 ratio.

**I want to know if cocos2d support scaled position.**

[image]

> this is some code.
>
> ```
>     CCSprite *green = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"green.png"];
>     CCSprite *yellow = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yellow.png"];
>     green.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
>     yellow.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
>
>     green.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
>     yellow.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
>
>     [green addChild:yellow];
>
>     [self addChild:green];
>
>     green.scale = 0.5;
>
>     CGPoint scaled = yellow.scaledposition(?) <=== How to get?
> ```

Comment: You already have the code, what's stopping you from actually running it and trying it out? It is a straightforward test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGPoint scaled = ccp(yellow.postion.x * green.scale, yellow.position.y * green.scale);
```

Comment: I want to know if cocos2d support scaled position.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I would loop through all children of the parent at the time you set the new scale and adjust the position according to the code I put in my answer.